# NDSolve: EventAction list specification using Table fails

Tags: differential-equations

I have an NDSolve problem that needs a list of a large number of events that are generated programmatically. Here is a simple example that demonstrates the problem on Mathematica 7 and 8 (the versions I have access to):

```
NDSolve[
  {y''[t] == 10, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0},
  {y},
  {t, 0, 1},
  Method -> {"EventLocator",
    "Event" :> {y[t] - 2, y[t] - 1},
    "EventAction" :>(*{Throw[Print["i=",1],"StopIntegration"],Throw[
     Print["i=",2],"StopIntegration"]}*)
     Table[Throw[Print["i=", i], "StopIntegration"], {i, 3}]
    }
  ];
```

The code as it is does not work (the second event should be triggered first, and it prints `i=1`), but if I use the commented block in `EventAction`, it does work, and prints `i=2`.

What is the right syntax to make this work? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that the `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) keeps the `Table` from being evaluated.  When `NDSolve` detects an event, it evaluates the appropriate event action.  In your code, the `"EventAction"` option is not (yet) an expression with head `List`, but an expression with head `Table`.  So instead of picking the corresponding part, `NDSolve` assumes that the whole expression should be evaluated for every event.  `Table` gets as far as `i = 1` and encounters `Throw`, which exits `Table` after printing `i = 1`.

You can check that the event `y[t] - 1` is the one that triggered the `"StopIntegration"` action as follows.

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] == 10, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, {y}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" :> {y[t] - 2, y[t] - 1}, 
    "EventAction" :>(*{Throw[Print["i=",1],"StopIntegration"],Throw[
     Print["i=",2],"StopIntegration"]}*)
     Table[Throw[Print["i=", i], "StopIntegration"], {i, 3}]}]
(*
  i=1

  {{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.447214}}, <>]}}
*)

{{ti, tf}} = y["Domain"] /. First[sol]
(*
  {{0., 0.447214}}
*)

y[tf] /. First[sol]
(*
   1.
*)
```

It's probably easiest to list the actions explicitly.

---

If you need to use `Table`, you could do it this way:

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] == 10, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, {y},
  {t, 0, 1},
  Method -> {"EventLocator",
    "Event" :> {y[t] - 2, y[t] - 1}, 
    With[{acts = Table[With[{i = i}, Hold@Throw[Print["i=", i], "StopIntegration"]], {i, 2}]},
     ("EventAction" :> acts) /. Hold[x_] :> x
     ]
    }]
```